# hybridauth : how to authenticate twitter user in yii framework

Tags: php, twitter, yii

I am following a tutorial from  http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/459/integrating-hybridauth-directly-into-yii-without-an-extension/

I included twitter login,

the problem is twitter is not returning email address

> Hybrid_User_Profile Object ( [identifier] => 2378654169 [webSiteURL]
>   => https://tisthedomainname.co/tpAnZH2BGe [profileURL] => http://twitter.com/myhjghj [photoURL] =>
>   http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/639065265478965088/8zty_o1K.png
>   [displayName] => myhjghj [description] => some text was here -
>   https://tisthedomainname.co/0yuxRheYVD [firstName] => myhjghj [lastName] => [gender]
>   => [language] => [age] => [birthDay] => [birthMonth] => [birthYear] => [email] => [emailVerified] => [phone] => [address] => [country] =>
>   [region] => United Kingdom [city] => [zip] => )

and in this url https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials 
(and also tell me how to use this url and when to use)
it is mentioned that

"If the user does not have an email address on their account, or if the email address is un-verified, null will be returned."

for facebook and google I am using the email address to login

```
public function login()
{
    $this->username = $this->userProfile->email;  //CUserIdentity
    Yii::app()->user->login($this, 0);
}
```

So How do I login the user if the user doesn't have email id in twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look in sourcecode of existing auth mechanisms, and take approaches from there.

For example: https://github.com/SleepWalker/hoauth. Here is how he explains his approach:

> When you planning to use social networks like Twitter, that returns no
>   email from user profile, you should declare verifyPassword($password)
>   or validatePassword($password) method in User model, that should take
>   the password (not hash) and return true if it is valid.
>
> You can also declare the sendActivationMail() method, that should mark
>   the user account as inactive and send the mail for activation. This
>   method, when it's exists will be used for social networks like
>   Twitter, that give us no data about user's email (because we need to
>   proof that user entered the right email).

Take a look and implement as you want to.